# Event_name parameter in gtag.js

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to migrate from Universal Anaylics to the newer Global Site Tag. I wish to migrate this code:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'MyCategory', 'MyAction', 'MyLabel', 1);
```

to:

```
gtag('event', '[EVENT_NAME???]', {'event_category':'MyCategory', 'event_label': 'MyLabel','event_action': 'MyAction','value':1});
```

I read https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events#recommended-events but I do not understand what the value for the event_name parameter should be and what the purpose of this value/parameter is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event name in gtag defaults to the event action in GA. If you use the "recommended event names" as provided by Google the gtag code will automatically insert category and label with predefined (by Google) values (which you may override). You can however also use custom event names (so you need only specify category and label in the JSON).

In the larger scheme of  things this is Google's attempt to unify web tracking and mobile tracking, since the suggested events for gtag.js match the recommended events for Firebase mobile tracking.